# AverageIF formula error causing error when retrieving data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to do an =AVERGEIF statement to retrieve the average of three pointers specific players made. I am getting a "Evaluation of function AVERAGEIF caused a divide by zero error".

The issue is located in "AIO REB & POINTS" sheet and the column for the threes made is 'NBA Players'!$BS3:$BS.

This is the formula I am using

```
=AVERAGEIF('NBA Players'!$B:$BT,$B3,'NBA Players'!$BS3:$BS)
```

It's the only stat from my sheet I can't get the averageif statement to work and I have no idea why.  I made sure the formate was set to number as well.

copy of sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RyxFzdmXu0upWHKAkbICVUUTVf_67KdEYhCy53XlD_s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BS column those aren't actually numbers. If you add Value before the Regex in BS, AverageIf works!

> =value(REGEXREPLACE(F4,"-.*",""))